# Count words in a Microsoft Word document by font?

Tags: vba, fonts, ms-word

I have a large document with code samples in. I want to know the word count for all text in font Calibri (Body), regardless of size. I want to ignore Consolas etc.

I have a macro that counts by italic (posted as an example) but can't get it to run.

```
Sub IgnoreItalics()
    Dim lngWord As Long, lngCountIt As Long

    lngCountIt = 0

    For lngWord = 1 To ActiveDocument.Words.Count
        If ActiveDocument.Words(lngWord).Italic Then
            lngCountIt = lngCountIt + 1
        End If
    Next lngWord

    MsgBox "Number of non-italic words: " & _
    ActiveDocument.BuiltInDocumentProperties("Number of words") -
    lngCountIt
End Sub
```

Any idea how to change this to Consolas?

Comment: What doesn't run about this? Are you getting an error, an invalid result, etc?

Comment: I think it may have been the document, it is 31k words long so last time it crashed under my environment, thought it may have been the code.

Comment: Interesting. In your code you use both `ActiveDocument.Words.Count` and `ActiveDocument.BuiltInDocumentProperties("Number of words")`. Have you tried using just on or the other in both positions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modifying your code so you can hopefully understand it, here is a solution that works     for me

```
Sub CountTypeface()
    Dim lngWord As Long
    Dim lngCountIt As Long
    Const Typeface As String = "Calibri"

    For lngWord = 1 To ActiveDocument.Words.Count
        'Ignore any document "Words" that aren't real words (CR, LF etc)
        If Len(Trim(ActiveDocument.Words(lngWord))) > 1 Then
            If ActiveDocument.Words(lngWord).Font.Name = Typeface Then
                lngCountIt = lngCountIt + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next lngWord

    MsgBox "Number of " & Typeface & " words: " & lngCountIt
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

For the record, changing your code just a *tad* worked for me:

```
Sub CountFonts()

Dim lngWord As Long, lngCountIt As Long
lngCountIt = 0
For lngWord = 1 To ActiveDocument.Words.Count
If ActiveDocument.Words(lngWord).Font.Name = "Calibri" Then
lngCountIt = lngCountIt + 1
End If
Next lngWord

MsgBox "Number of non-Calibri words: " & _
ActiveDocument.BuiltInDocumentProperties("Number of words") - lngCountIt
End Sub
```

Comment: Looks like it works, i will mark correct once the code finishes. word is not responding at the mo but it's a large document so hopefully just taknig its time.

Answer (score -1):

use

```
ActiveDocument.ComputeStatistics(wdStatisticWords)
```

or

```
ActiveDocument.ComputeStatistics(0)
```