# How to count words in a Microsoft Word document by Color using VBA?

Tags: vba, count, ms-word

Would it be possible to count color word inside a Word document? Let say there are two color word in my document. I need to count the word that is the color Blue and I need to count the word that is the color Red.

I only found [Count words in a Microsoft Word document by Fonts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9720764/count-words-in-a-microsoft-word-document-by-font)

```
Sub CountTypeface()
    Dim lngWord As Long
    Dim lngCountIt As Long
    Const Typeface As String = "Cambria"

    For lngWord = 1 To ActiveDocument.Words.Count
        'Ignore any document "Words" that aren't real words (CR, LF etc)
        If Len(Trim(ActiveDocument.Words(lngWord))) > 1 Then
            If ActiveDocument.Words(lngWord).Font.Name = Typeface Then
                lngCountIt = lngCountIt + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next lngWord

    MsgBox "Number of " & Typeface & " words: " & lngCountIt
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub CountTypeface()
    Dim lngWord As Long
    Dim lngCountIt As Long
    Const ColorIndex As Long = 6

    For lngWord = 1 To ActiveDocument.Words.Count
        If Len(Trim(ActiveDocument.Words(lngWord))) > 1 Then
            Debug.Print ActiveDocument.Words(lngWord).Font.ColorIndex
            If ActiveDocument.Words(lngWord).Font.ColorIndex = ColorIndex Then
                lngCountIt = lngCountIt + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next lngWord

    MsgBox "Number of colored words: " & lngCountIt
End Sub
```

6 is for red. If you put a small text in Word and you color a few words, it would print them their colors in the immediate window, before giving you the messagebox. Thus, you would learn the number of the colors.

Comment: Thanks Vitaya it works. As for the number of colors, could you advice the web page that I can use for reference. Thanks so much.

Comment: The best option is simply to make a check yourself, with writing just one word and seeing its color when you run it. It would print in the immediate window. Otherwise with pages it is a bit tough, but try http://dmcritchie.mvps.org/excel/colors.htm