# Count words in a Microsoft Word document by document style?

Tags: vba, ms-word

In analogy to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9720764/count-words-in-a-microsoft-word-document-by-font), I would like to script a VBA script that counts words formatted with a certain document style, more precisely: a certain paragraph style.

```
Sub CountTypeface()
    Dim lngWord As Long
    Dim lngCountIt As Long
    Const Typeface As String = "Calibri"
    Const MyFormat As String = "My Paragraph Style"
    'Ignore any document "Words" that aren't real words (CR, LF etc)
    For lngWord = 1 To ActiveDocument.Words.Count
        If Len(Trim(ActiveDocument.Words(lngWord))) > 1 Then
            If ActiveDocument.Styles(lngWord) = MyFormat Then
                lngCountIt = lngCountIt + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next lngWord

    MsgBox "Number of " & Typeface & " words: " & lngCountIt
End Sub
```

But running this code results in the runtime error:
runtime error "5941".: the requested member of the collection does not exist

Why does this happen and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using your word count iterator as the index for the `style` collection. You have more words than `Styles` has indices, and the `If` would only be true one time, since you aren't checking the word's style.

Replace:

```
If ActiveDocument.Styles(lngWord) = MyFormat Then
```

With:

```
If ActiveDocument.Words(lngWord).Style = MyFormat Then
```